Drone_Controlling with teleop_twist_keyboard does not work
Hello Robotics_community,
I am trying to make a drone with meshes and i want to controll it with Ros2-Controller (Keyboard)
just to make sure i am a beginner with it.
The problem i got is that i cannot controll my drone at all. i searched everywhere and tried everything i can but i could not find the problem.
Can someone help me to make it move at least in +Z Axis and -Z Axis so i can say i finally did something.
i am using Ubuntu Humble with Ros2 and Gazebo.
i hope i gave every needed details so someone can help me out.
rsp.launch.py:
> import os from ament_index_python.packages import
> get_package_share_directory from launch import LaunchDescription from
> launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument from launch.substitutions
> import LaunchConfiguration from launch_ros.actions import Node from
> launch.substitutions import Command, PathJoinSubstitution from
> launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
> 
> def generate_launch_description():
>     use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
> 
>     pkg_path = FindPackageShare('my_bot')
>     xacro_file = PathJoinSubstitution([pkg_path, 'description', 'robot.urdf.xacro'])
> 
>     robot_description_config = Command(['xacro ', xacro_file])
>     params = {'robot_description': robot_description_config, 'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}
> 
>     node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
>         package='robot_state_publisher',
>         executable='robot_state_publisher',
>         output='screen',
>         parameters=[params]
>     )
> 
>     return LaunchDescription([
>         DeclareLaunchArgument(
>             'use_sim_time',
>             default_value='false',
>             description='Use sim time if true'
>         ),
>         node_robot_state_publisher
>     ])

launcher_sim.launch.py:
> import os
> from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
> from launch import LaunchDescription
> from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, DeclareLaunchArgument, TimerAction
> from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
> from launch_ros.actions import Node
> from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
> 
> def generate_launch_description():
>     package_name = 'my_bot'
> 
>     rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
>         PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
>             get_package_share_directory(package_name), 'launch', 'rsp.launch.py'
>         )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'true'}.items()
>     )
> 
>     gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
>         PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
>             get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py'
>         )]),
>     )
> 
>     spawn_entity = Node(
>         package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
>         arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description', '-entity', 'my_bot'],
>         output='screen'
>     )
> 
>     joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
>         package="controller_manager",
>         executable="spawner",
>         arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster"],
>         output="screen"
>     )
> 
>     velocity_controller_spawner = Node(
>         package="controller_manager",
>         executable="spawner",
>         arguments=["velocity_controller"],
>         output="screen"
>     )
> 
>     use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
> 
>     joy_params = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('my_bot'), 'config', 'joystick.yaml')
> 
>     joy_node = Node(
>         package='joy',
>         executable='joy_node',
>         parameters=[joy_params, {'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
>     )
> 
>     teleop_node = Node(
>         package='teleop_twist_joy',
>         executable='teleop_node',
>         name='teleop_node',
>         parameters=[joy_params, {'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
>         remappings=[('/cmd_vel','/new_cmd_vel')]
>     )
> 
>     teleop_twist_keyboard = Node(
>         package='teleop_twist_keyboard',
>         executable='teleop_twist_keyboard',
>         name='teleop_twist_keyboard',
>         output='screen',
>         remappings=[('/cmd_vel', '/new_cmd_vel')]
>     )
> 
>     return LaunchDescription([
>         rsp,
>         gazebo,
>         spawn_entity,
> 
>         TimerAction(
>             period=5.0,
>             actions=[joint_state_broadcaster_spawner]
>         ),
>         TimerAction(
>             period=10.0,
>             actions=[velocity_controller_spawner]
>         ),
>         DeclareLaunchArgument(
>             'use_sim_time',
>             default_value='false',
>             description='Use sim time if true',
>         ),
>         joy_node,
>         teleop_node,
>         teleop_twist_keyboard,
>     ])

drone.urdf.xacro:
> <robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
> 
>   <gazebo>
>     <plugin name="gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
>       <robot_param>robot_description</robot_param>
>       <robot_param_node>robot_state_publisher</robot_param_node>
>       <parameters>/home/alba/dev_ws/src/my_bot/config/rotor_controller.yaml</parameters>
>     </plugin>
>   </gazebo>
> 
> 
>   <ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
>     <hardware>
>         <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
>     </hardware>
> 
>     <joint name="base_to_b1">
>         <command_interface name="velocity"/>
>         <state_interface name="velocity"/>
>     </joint>
>     <joint name="base_to_b2">
>         <command_interface name="velocity"/>
>         <state_interface name="velocity"/>
>     </joint>
>     <joint name="base_to_b3">
>         <command_interface name="velocity"/>
>         <state_interface name="velocity"/>
>     </joint>
>     <joint name="base_to_b4">
>         <command_interface name="velocity"/>
>         <state_interface name="velocity"/>
>     </joint>
>   </ros2_control>
> 
> </robot>

rotor_controller.yaml:
> controller_manager:
>     ros__parameters:
>       update_rate: 50
>       use_sim_time: true
>       joint_state_broadcaster:
>        type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
>       velocity_controller:
>        type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController
>        
> velocity_controller:
>   ros__parameters:
>     joints:
>       - base_to_b1
>       - base_to_b2
>       - base_to_b3
>       - base_to_b4

joystick.yaml:
> joy_node:
>   ros__parameters:
>     device_id: 0
>     deadzone: 0.05
>     autorepeat_rate: 20.0
> 
> teleop_node:
>   ros__parameters:
>     axis_linear:
>       z: 4
>     scale_linear:
>       z: 2.0
>     scale_linear_turbo:
>       z: 5.0
> 
>     axis_linear:
>       x: 0
>     scale_linear:
>       x: 5.0
>     scale_linear_turbo:
>       x: 10.0
> 
>     axis_angular:
>       yaw: 1
>     scale_angular:
>       yaw: 5.0
>     scale_angular_turbo:
>       yaw: 10.0
> 
>     axis_linear:
>       y: 3
>     scale_linear:
>       y: 5.0
>     scale_linear_turbo:
>       y: 10.0
> 
>     enable_turbo_button: 1
> 
>     require_enable_button: false

and just in case you need the log to make sure:
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/alba/.ros/log/2024-09-19-14-49-18-788212-alba-4163
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [4166]
[INFO] [gzserver-2]: process started with pid [4168]
[INFO] [gzclient-3]: process started with pid [4170]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [4172]
[INFO] [joy_node-5]: process started with pid [4174]
[INFO] [teleop_node-6]: process started with pid [4176]
[teleop_node-6] [INFO] [1726750161.682192441] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Turbo on button 1.
[teleop_node-6] [INFO] [1726750161.682370041] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Linear axis x on 0 at scale 5.000000.
[teleop_node-6] [INFO] [1726750161.682422641] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Turbo for linear axis x is scale 10.000000.
[teleop_node-6] [INFO] [1726750161.682471641] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Linear axis y on 3 at scale 5.000000.
[teleop_node-6] [INFO] [1726750161.682518341] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Turbo for linear axis y is scale 10.000000.
[teleop_node-6] [INFO] [1726750161.682565141] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Linear axis z on 4 at scale 2.000000.
[teleop_node-6] [INFO] [1726750161.682612841] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Turbo for linear axis z is scale 5.000000.
[teleop_node-6] [INFO] [1726750161.682659641] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Angular axis yaw on 1 at scale 5.000000.
[teleop_node-6] [INFO] [1726750161.682956741] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Turbo for angular axis yaw is scale 10.000000.
[robot_state_publisher-1] [WARN] [1726750161.806138669] [kdl_parser]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1726750161.806511869] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment b1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1726750161.806995869] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment b2
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1726750161.807079069] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment b3
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1726750161.807158569] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment b4
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1726750161.807236669] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1726750161.807315069] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment cam
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1726750161.807393269] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment land
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1726750163.485488247] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1726750163.490059849] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
[spawn_entity.py-4]   warnings.warn(
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1726750163.511889853] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1726750163.548037562] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1726750163.552380363] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[gzclient-3] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[gzclient-3] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[gzclient-3] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[gzclient-3] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[gzserver-2] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[gzserver-2] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[gzserver-2] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[gzserver-2] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1726750165.862268983] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [4321]
[gzclient-3] 
[gzclient-3] libcurl: (6) Could not resolve host: fuel.ignitionrobotics.org
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1726750166.805391196] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [my_bot]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 4172]
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1726750167.796919320] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750167.913570246] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading gazebo_ros2_control plugin
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750167.948584454] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in namespace: /
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750167.949257654] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in ros 2 node: gazebo_ros2_control
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750167.968664058] [gazebo_ros2_control]: connected to service!! robot_state_publisher
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750167.976233760] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Received urdf from param server, parsing...
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750167.976625460] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading parameter files /home/alba/dev_ws/src/my_bot/config/rotor_controller.yaml
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.034078373] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: base_to_b1
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.034458373] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   State:
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.034875573] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.035126073] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   Command:
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.035369373] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.035621373] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: base_to_b2
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.036117173] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   State:
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.036366973] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.036611973] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   Command:
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.037036873] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.037300074] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: base_to_b3
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.037549074] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   State:
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.037991274] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.038238174] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   Command:
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.038482574] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.038944574] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: base_to_b4
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.039244774] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   State:
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.039493774] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.039933974] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   Command:
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.040179774] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.040526874] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'GazeboSystem' 
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.041151274] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'GazeboSystem'
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.042096974] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'GazeboSystem' 
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.042257675] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'GazeboSystem'
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.042413775] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'GazeboSystem' 
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.042566575] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'GazeboSystem'
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.043140975] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading controller_manager
[gzserver-2] [WARN] [1726750168.233546918] [gazebo_ros2_control]:  Desired controller update period (0.02 s) is slower than the gazebo simulation period (0.001 s).
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.236298719] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loaded gazebo_ros2_control.
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.314883936] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1726750168.461951169] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.471040171] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750168.471481972] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1726750168.587148598] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 4321]
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process started with pid [4358]
[gzclient-3] context mismatch in svga_surface_destroy
[gzclient-3] context mismatch in svga_surface_destroy
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750173.484798102] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'velocity_controller'
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1726750173.815989176] [spawner_velocity_controller]: Loaded velocity_controller
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750173.820977778] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'velocity_controller'
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750173.830970380] [velocity_controller]: configure successful
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726750173.869233289] [velocity_controller]: activate successful
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1726750173.902301196] [spawner_velocity_controller]: Configured and activated velocity_controller
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process has finished cleanly [pid 4358]

Command what i use to turn it on:

ros2 launch my_bot launch_sim.launch.py

remapping
`

ros2 run teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard --ros-args -r /cmd_vel:=/new_cmd_vel

i thought i have to turn the velocity controller by myself so the rotors start to move:

ros2 topic pub /velocity_controller/commands std_msgs/msg/Float64MultiArray "data: [50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5]"


Are the joints base_to_b* the rotors? Do you use any plugins for modeling aerodynamic forces? gazebo classic won't do that automatically for you, see https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/110561/33182 for example.
What happens if you send topics to /velocity_controller/commands via ros2 topic pub? Do the rotors spin?

Hi, yes base_to_b* are the rotors of the drone. when i use the command: '/velocity_controller/commands' via 'ros2 topic pub'
the rotors (in this case base_to_b*) start moving. if i put 50 for all 4 of them drone moves randomly and leaves the map. (like this one
'ros2 topic pub /velocity_controller/commands std_msgs/msg/Float64MultiArray "data: [50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5]"')

if this is the case, then the aerodynamics are somehow calculated? after all, you will need an attitude controller for your drone

i dont know what are aerodynamics, i am gonna check on it. i thought i could control it from Keyboard though teleop_twist_keyboard.
Can you tell me more about it and what you recommand to use / to do ?

See the link above, gazebo classic does not calculate aerodynamics without additional plugins. and your drone is an unstable system, without attitude controller it won't fly stable.

ty for helping out. i am still trying to make it work out. i alread tried this idea of aerodynamics. it did not make any diferent.
someone told me i could use the idea of sjtu_drone (https://github.com/NovoG93/sjtu_drone/blob/ros2/sjtu_drone_bringup/launch/sjtu_drone_bringup.launch.py) but its too complicated for me
what do you think, is it a good idea to try to find a solution there or its not worth the time and work ?
